# inject multiple templates as HTML into directive and compile to the directives scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I'm developing a custom angular directive whos main goal is to display a data grid. I want to allow users of my directive to inject their own html cell templates into it, which will override the standard cell rendering mechanism. I could of course let users define their cell templates in a json config object and transmit this into my directive using attributes, but I think a better approach is to let users specify their templates directly as HTML.

**Intended use**

```
    <my-grid config="config" data="data">
      <cell field="active">
        <!-- User templates given here for specific columns -->
      </cell>
    </my-grid>
```

Right now, I'm using the transclude method of the link function in my directive to collect the `<cell>` templates available to the directives controller. 
But the transclude function returns compiled html, and the scope the html is compiled in is of course the controller of the page `<my-grid>` is used in. This means that the cell template injected cannot possibly be transcluded using values from the data given to the grid directive in place.

In order to acchieve this, everything inside `<cell>` needs to be injected uncompiled. But this seems to be impossible. I even hooked up to the compile method to see if I could get the given `<cell>` elements directly from the $element input argument, but even this is too late. At this point templates from other included directives has allready been included, overwriting the `<cell>` elements.

Does anybody have any tips as to how I can acheive what I'm trying to do?

**My directive**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
        'use strict';

        // Simplified metadata for the grid structure
        $scope.config = {
            columns: [{name: 'id'}, {name: 'name'}, {name: 'active'}, {name: 'comment'}]
        };

        // Provide data for the directive
        $scope.data = [
            {id: 1, name: 'test1', active: true, comment: 'Contains something'},
            {id: 2, name: 'test2', active: false, comment: 'Another comment'}
        ];
    })
    .directive('myGrid', ['$timeout', '$compile', function ($timeout, $compile) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict        : 'E',
            templateUrl     : 'grid/templates/gridPanel.html',
            transclude      : true,
            controllerAs    : 'gridCtrl',
            bindToController: true,
            scope           : {
                config: '=',
                data  : '='
            },
            controller      : ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
                var ctrl = this;
                $timeout(function () {
                    var elToReplace = $('[tpl]', $element);
                    elToReplace.replaceWith(ctrl.getTemplate($compile(elToReplace.attr('tpl'))($scope)));
                });
                ctrl.getTemplate = function (column) {
                    return (ctrl.templates[column] ? ctrl.templates[column] : ctrl.templates['__ALL__']);
                }
            }],
            compile         : function compile ($element, $attrs, transclude) {
                var origEl = $element; // $element allready contains the directive template here. <cell> is unobtainable.
                return function postLink ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {

                    // This provides a list of <cell> elements, but they are allready compiled in the scope they are provided in.
                    $transclude(function (overrides) {
                        ctrl.templates = _.chain(overrides)
                            .filter(function (content) {
                                return content.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'CELL';
                            })
                            .indexBy(function (content) {
                                return $(content).attr('field');
                            })
                            .value();
                        ctrl.templates['__ALL__'] = '<span>{{ row[column.name] }}</span>';
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }])
    .run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
        'use strict';
        $templateCache.put('grid/templates/gridPanel.html',
            '<div class="panel panel-default">' +
            '  <header class="panel-heading">' +
            '    TEST-GRID' +
            '  </header>' +
            '  <div class="panel-body">' +
            '    <table class="table table-condensed">' +
            '      <thead>' +
            '        <tr>' +
            '          <th ng-repeat="column in gridCtrl.config.columns track by column.name">' +
            '            {{ column.name }}' +
            '          </th>' +
            '        </tr>' +
            '      </thead>' +
            '      <tbody>' +
            '        <tr ng-repeat="row in gridCtrl.data track by $index">' +
            '          <td ng-repeat="column in gridCtrl.config.columns track by column.name">' +
            '            <span tpl="column"></span>' + // This is where the cell template should be rendered.
            '          </td>' +
            '        </tr>' +
            '      </tbody>' +
            '    </table>' +
            '  </div>' +
            '</div>');
    }]);
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.3.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>My grid setup</h2>
    <my-grid config="config" data="data">
      <cell field="active">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.active" />
        </label>
      </cell>
    </my-grid>
  </div>
</div>
```

This does not work. First of all, it does not transcludes the template as it should. It only transcludes what I've set up as a 'default template', and this is transcluded as cleartext. Not compiled. If I try to compile it in the scope, angular yields an indefinate digest loop.

Comment: why dont you just have them give you a string of html and then use that to compile and use. I don't think I fully understand what you are trying to do and how you expect people to give you html.

Comment: As I said in the question, I could get them to inject the HTML in a json config string and pass that in as an attribute to the directive (see params="" above), but I think that a better approach is to let users specify their template as HTML (see contents of cell element above)

Comment: Maybe you should create a plunker of your problem. You could try using a textarea instead of a cell which would give you their html as a string, and you could compile that. Hard to say, your issue and needs are unclear.

Comment: Have included a runnable code snippet which describes my directive and how it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The secret was that the transclude function receives the scope. I just had to save it, and use that when compiling the template. :-)

Below is a version of my directives which work as expected!

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
        'use strict';

        // Simplified metadata for the grid structure
        $scope.config = {
            columns: [{name: 'id'}, {name: 'name'}, {name: 'active'}, {name: 'comment'}]
        };

        // Provide data for the directive
        $scope.data = [
            {id: 1, name: 'test1', active: true, comment: 'Contains something'},
            {id: 2, name: 'test2', active: false, comment: 'Another comment'}
        ];
    })
    .directive('myGrid', ['$timeout', '$compile', function ($timeout, $compile) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict        : 'E',
            templateUrl     : 'grid/templates/gridPanel.html',
            transclude      : true,
            controllerAs    : 'gridCtrl',
            bindToController: true,
            scope           : {
                config: '=',
                data  : '='
            },
            link            : function postLink ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
                // Set default cell template
                var defaultTemplates = [
                    $('<cell field="__ALL__"><span>{{ row[column.name] }}</span></cell>').get(0)
                ];
                // Collect cell templates given -----------------
                $transclude(function(overrides, futureScope) {
                    var transcluded = {
                        tpls: _.filter(overrides, function (content) {
                            return content.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'CELL';
                        }),
                        scope: futureScope
                    };
                    transcluded.tpls = transcluded.tpls.concat(defaultTemplates); // Insert defaults
                  
                    // Expose cell templates to controller scope
                    ctrl.cellTemplates = _.chain(transcluded.tpls)
                        // Group by column name
                        .groupBy(function(tpl)   { return $(tpl).attr('field'); })
                    
                        // Create the template object
                        .mapValues(function(tpl) {
                            var template = $(tpl).html().trim();
                            return {
                                tpl: template,
                                isTranscluded: $(tpl).hasClass('ng-scope'),
                                origScope: ($(tpl).hasClass('ng-scope') ? transcluded.scope : null), // Save the original scope the template was given in
                                compiledFn: $compile(template) // Precompile templates
                            };
                        })
                        .value();
                    
                    // Create convenience method to retrieve template based on column name
                    ctrl.getTemplate = function (column) {
                        return _.has(ctrl.cellTemplates, column.name) ? ctrl.cellTemplates[column.name] : ctrl.cellTemplates.__ALL__;
                    }

                });

            },
            controller      : ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
                var ctrl = this;
            }]
        };
    }])
    .directive('myGridCell', function () {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require : '^^myGrid',
            scope   : {
                column  : '=myGridCell', // This is the configuration object for this column
                row     : '=',           // Contains the data for the entire row
                rowIndex: '='            // The row index in the grids dataset
            },
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {
                var me = {
                    childScope: null,
                    renderTemplate: function () {
                        $element.empty();
                        // Retrieve template for the given column
                        var tpl = ctrl.getTemplate($scope.column);

                        // Cleanup old fun
                        if (me.childScope && me.childScope.$id !== $scope.$id) {
                            me.childScope.$destroy();
                        }
                        // Get or create the child scope
                        if (tpl.isTranscluded) {
                            // Create a new scope as a child of the one transcluded
                            me.childScope            = tpl.origScope.$new();
                            
                            // Attach important properties to newly created scope
                            me.childScope.row        = $scope.row;
                            me.childScope.column     = $scope.column;
                            me.childScope.rowIndex   = $scope.rowIndex;
                        } else {
                            me.childScope = $scope;
                        }
                        // Attach controller to childScope
                        me.childScope.gridCtrl = ctrl;

                        // Apply the template in the appropriate scope
                        tpl.compiledFn(me.childScope, function (clonedElement, scope) {
                            scope.$element = clonedElement;
                            $element.append(clonedElement);
                        });
                    }
                }
                me.renderTemplate();
            }
        }
    })
    .run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
        'use strict';
        $templateCache.put('grid/templates/gridPanel.html',
            '<div class="panel panel-default">' +
            '  <header class="panel-heading">' +
            '    TEST-GRID' +
            '  </header>' +
            '  <div class="panel-body">' +
            '    <table class="table table-condensed">' +
            '      <thead>' +
            '        <tr>' +
            '          <th ng-repeat="column in gridCtrl.config.columns track by column.name">' +
            '            {{ column.name }}' +
            '          </th>' +
            '        </tr>' +
            '      </thead>' +
            '      <tbody>' +
            '        <tr ng-repeat="(rowIndex, row) in gridCtrl.data track by $index">' +
            '          <td ng-repeat="column in gridCtrl.config.columns track by column.name" my-grid-cell="column" row="row" row-index="rowIndex">' +
            '          </td>' +
            '        </tr>' +
            '      </tbody>' +
            '    </table>' +
            '  </div>' +
            '</div>');
    }]);
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.3.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>My grid setup</h2>
    <my-grid config="config" data="data">
      <cell field="active">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.active" />
        </label>
      </cell>
    </my-grid>
  </div>
</div>
```